# How to get RSS feeds from the web and display them in a custom list view

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I wrote this code to display news feeds ( RSS feeds ) after parsing in a custom list view .. but I had an exception and actually I don't know where is the problem or how to solve this exception !!

**Edit :**

I've solved this problem by changing the position of :

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feedsTitles);

             feedsList.setAdapter(new TempLyaout(MainActivity.this,feedsTitles));
```

to be instead of :

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

SO I got the RSS feeds and display them in a custom list view ^__^

**MainActivity class :**

```
package com.example.testfeeds;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String name;
    Button getfeeds;
    ArrayList<String> feedsTitles;
    ArrayList<String> feedsLinks;
    ListView feedsList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ProgressDialog progress ;



    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getfeeds = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        feedsList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        progress = new ProgressDialog(this); 
        progress.setMessage("Loading .... "); 
        progress.setCancelable(false); 

        feedsTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        feedsLinks = new ArrayList<String>();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feedsTitles);

         feedsList.setAdapter(new TempLyaout(MainActivity.this,feedsTitles));

        getfeeds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            new GetFeeds().execute("http://yunn.yu.edu.jo/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=55&layout=blog&Itemid=104&format=feed&type=rss"); 

            }
        });

        feedsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                    long id) {



                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(feedsLinks.get(position)));

                startActivity(browserIntent);

            }
        });



    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     class GetFeeds extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                progress.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            String xmlData = GetUrlBody(arg0[0]); 

            Log.d("msg","in doInBackground .. ");


            return xmlData ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.d("msg","the result not null");

            ////--------------------------------------////

            //Log.d("msg",result);

            FileOutputStream makeXml = null ; //declare a file to store the incoming xml data.
            InputStream xmlFile = null; // declare an input stream to get the xml file.
            try {


                makeXml= openFileOutput("temp.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                makeXml.write(result.getBytes());
                makeXml.flush();
                makeXml.close(); 

                xmlFile= openFileInput("temp.xml"); 



            } catch (IOException e) {


                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          ////--------------------------------------////


            XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;

            try {
                pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
                    parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    parser.setInput(xmlFile, null);
                    parseXML(parser);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            progress.dismiss();

        }




     }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        String GetUrlBody (String Url ){

            Log.d("msg","in get url ..");

        HttpClient cli = new DefaultHttpClient(); 



        HttpGet g = new HttpGet(Url); 



        try{
        HttpResponse res = cli.execute(g);



        if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){

            String s =
        EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8); 

            return s; 

        }else {
            return "Not Found"; 
        }

        }catch(Exception exx){}


        return null; 
    }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
        {

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            int getElement=0;
            String title,link,pubDate;


            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

                String tagName = null;


                switch (eventType){

                //----------------------------------//
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT: 
                    feedsTitles.clear();
                    feedsLinks.clear();
                    break;
               //----------------------------------//
                 case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                     tagName = parser.getName();
                     if ("item".equals(tagName)){
                          getElement=1;
                     } else if (getElement==1){
                         if ("title".equals(tagName)){
                             title = parser.nextText();
                             Log.d("value",title);
                             feedsTitles.add(title);
                         } else if ("link".equals(tagName)){
                            link = parser.nextText();
                            Log.d("value",link);
                            feedsLinks.add(link);
                         } else if ("pubDate".equals(tagName)){
                             pubDate= parser.nextText();
                             Log.d("value",pubDate);
                         }
                     }
                     break;                     
               //----------------------------------//
                 case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                     tagName = parser.getName();
                     if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("item") && getElement != 0){

                     }

                     break;

              //----------------------------------//


                }// end-switch.


                eventType= parser.next();

            }// end-while.


        } //end xmlParser method.


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


} // end- MainActivity class.
```

**Custom list view class :**

```
package com.example.testfeeds;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TempLyaout extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> sa;




    public TempLyaout(Context context , ArrayList<String> sa) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_view,sa);
        this.context=context;
        this.sa = sa;
    }





    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = l.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        textView.setText(sa.get(position));


        return rowView;
    }




}
```

**StackTrece :**

```
07-27 09:55:40.866: D/AndroidRuntime(6035): Shutting down VM
07-27 09:55:40.866: W/dalvikvm(6035): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at com.example.testfeeds.MainActivity.parseXML(MainActivity.java:286)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at com.example.testfeeds.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:227)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at com.example.testfeeds.MainActivity$GetFeeds.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:169)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at com.example.testfeeds.MainActivity$GetFeeds.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you sure the server is returning a valid response?

Comment: @blackbelt: yes .. and you can see the log messages with tag "value" in the stack trace ... ^^

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 09:55:40.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6035):     at com.example.testfeeds.MainActivity.parseXML(MainActivity.java:286)`  Let's start with "which one is line 286?"

Comment: @Simon: when I've made a comment on "adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);" I haven't gotten the exception i.e. this statement is  the cause of exception and I don't know why!!

Comment: It seems your ParseXML function is not returning the expected value, we need to start with line 286

Comment: It seems your adapter's value is not changing, and that's why it cannot return a boolean value. If your adapter is not changed in some situations then it does not change and hence nothing to return, which inturn returns a null pointer. If you need to get notified only when the adapter is changed, you might surround your statement with a try catch block

Comment: @Balavishnu: when I've did as ur advice and surrounded this statement by try and catch I've gotten the same exception so for sure now the problem is that the adapter hasn't changed !!

Comment: Put a breakpoint on line 286.  Inspect the variables.  Which one is null?

Comment: Thanks Mrs Simon , thank u all .. I've solved the problem and updated my post .. thanks a lot :))))